# Вывод шаблона в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Я использую один главный шаблон и есть другой подшаблон (я его так называю). Например, когда у меня страница вида

```
http://site.ru/main/profile
```

то у меня дополнительно подгружается шаблон profile.php, который является подшаблоном main.php.

Мне надо написать метод, который всегда буде вызываться, даже если страница будет вида

```
http://site.ru/main/profile/edit
```

У меня есть контроллер ProfileController. Когда первая ссылка - вызывается действие actionIndex, когда вторая - actionEdit.

Какой метод мне написать, что бы он вызывался в обоих случаях?

Comment: я так и не понял что должно вызываться в обоих случаях. контроллер, экшн контроллера или подшаблон profile

Comment: мне  нужно что бы какое то действие контроллера ProfileController выполнялось всегда, когда задействован этот контроллер

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы выполнить нечто до или после действия, у [yii\base\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html) есть два метода, [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail) - выполняется перед любым действием, и [afterAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#afterAction()-detail) - выполняется после любого действия

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\base\Controller;

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function beforeAction($action) {
        //...
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function afterAction($action, $result)
    {
        //..
        return parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    }
}
```